# LU decomposition without pivoting for symmetric definite negative matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices, lu-decomposition

While studying LU decomposition from [this book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540346586) I came across the statement that **pivoting in LU decomposition is not necessary in some cases, as for example when the matrix is symmetric positive definite**.

Then what about symmetric **negative** definite matrices? I couldn't find a counter-example. My specific concern is for the symmetric definite negative matrix that arises from the [discretization of the stiff equation](http://www.nada.kth.se/~jjalap/numme/FDheat.pdf), i.e. a matrix like

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
1 & -2 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 1 & -2 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: If $A$ is neg. def., then $-A$ is pos. def., can you get the LU factorization of $A$ from the LU factorization of $-A$?

Comment: Yes indeed, but wouldn't the linear system then have a different solution? I know this is a different question though.

Comment: Well, you can always solve $-Ax=-b$ instead of $Ax = b$.

Comment: Haha you're right it's simple. Do you mind posting both your comments as an answer? I'll accept it

Comment: a bit late, but done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can construct the LU factorization of a negative definite matrix $A$ by considering its positive definite counterpart $-A$. So $-A = LU$ (since $-A$ is positive definite) and hence $A = L(-U)$.

Alternatively, you can also solve $-Ax = -b$ directly, which is equivalent to the original question.

Comment: Fix the sign of b?

Comment: @Eugenio Sorry, just came back from vacation and had a rough trip home. Should be fixed now.